# 1970's house new light fixture with connectors

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture, ceiling

Installing ceiling light fixture in a 1970's house. The new fixture has push-in connectors to all wires (black/white/ground). I am replacing an old light/heater which was grounded to screw in the housing box in ceiling. Should I take the connector off of the ground from fixture and place around screw? Or, just place the ground into the new ground/connector? There is a ground screw attached to the metal back of new light fixture.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you have an old system that uses the metal boxes to provide a ground.

If I am understanding you correctly, you have an existing ground wire attached to a screw in the original ceiling box.

If that is correct, attach that wire to the new ground wire lead to the light fixture. ( Connecting via the push in connector is ok, But Us old school guys prefer the wire nuts.)

If this is incorrect and you have nothing to push into the new ground connector, you can add a wire to the ground screw in the ceiling box and push it into the new fixture ground connector.

OR, if there is enough wire, just cut off the push in connector on the green ground wire and attach it to the screw in the ceiling box.

Comment: Thanks, I am also old school , tried wrapping the ground around screw leaving enough to insert into connector, not enough wire, so I had to insert the ground (could not wrap around screw) into the connector on fixture. Will adding a wire to the screw in box and inserting it into connector provide enough ground?

Comment: That should be good for you.